# Second and the third gets() function in C are not working

Tags: c

The compiler does not show any error but the second and the third `gets()` functions do not seem to work as expected. Instead the next line of code gets executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char name[100], result[100];
    int marks;
} s1, s2, s3;

main() {
    printf("Enter the name of the student s1:");
    gets(s1.name);
    printf("Enter the marks obtained by the student s1:");
    scanf("%d", &s1.marks);
    printf("Enter the name of the student s2:");
    gets(s2.name);
    printf("Enter the marks obtained by the student s2: ");
    scanf("%d", &s2.marks);
    printf("Enter the name of the student s3:");
    gets(s3.name);
    printf("Enter the marks of the student s3:");
    scanf("%d", &s3.marks);
    if ((s1.marks > s2.marks) & (s1.marks > s3.marks))
        printf("the student s1 has got the highest marks");
    else 
    if ((s2.marks > s3.marks))
        printf("The student s2 has got the highest marks");
    else
        printf("The student s3 has got the highest marks");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially not as links which can disappear (and make the question worthless). Copy-paste the actual text into the body of the question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are mixing up `gets` (which is deprecated<sup>*</sup>) and `scanf`.

End-of-line mark from `scanf` remains in the buffer, so when `gets` tries to read the next input, it treats it as an empty line.

You can fix this by using `scanf` for all your input, including strings:

```
printf("Enter the name of the student s1:");
scanf("%99s", s1.name); // Use "%99[^\n]" to allow multi-part names
printf("Enter the marks obtained by the student s1:");
scanf("%d", &s1.marks);
```

<sup>*</sup> `gets` is deprecated, so you should use `fgets(s1.name, sizeof(s1.name), stdin)` instead. Here is a reference for [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html).

Comment: Yes it did work when I used scanf function. Thank you for helping me get a deeper understanding of the above functions.

Comment: @chqrlie Thank you very much! The argument order was also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scanf("%d ",&s1.marks);`. The space after `%d` would escape the `\n` that you enter after the number. If we do not do that, `gets()` will read `"\n"` as the next string input.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student { 
  char name[100], result[100]; 
  int marks; 
} s1,s2,s3; 

int main() {
  printf("Enter the name of the student s1:"); 
  scanf("%s", s1.name);  
  printf("Enter the marks obtained by the student s1:"); 
  scanf("%d", &s1.marks); 
  printf("Enter the name of the student s2:"); 
  scanf("%s", s2.name); 
  printf("Enter the marks obtained by the student s2: "); 
  scanf("%d", &s2.marks); 
  printf("Enter the name of the student s3:"); 
  scanf("%s", s3.name); 
  printf("Enter the marks of the student s3:"); 
  scanf("%d", &s3.marks); 
  if ((s1.marks > s2.marks) && (s1.marks > s3.marks)) 
      printf("the student s1 has got the highest marks"); 
  else if((s2.marks > s3.marks)) 
      printf("The student s2 has got the highest marks"); 
  else 
      printf("The student s3 has got the highest marks");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Removing `gets()` fixes the trailing `'\n'` issue, but `scanf("%s",...)` is just as risky as `gets()`, and has different semantics.